# Is principle of superposition valid for extended conducting objects whose charge distribution is affected by presence of other charges nearby?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

let me explain my question with an example. Say we put a charge at the centre of an metallic hollow charged sphere and measure electric field at a distance larger than the radius. It is easy to calculate.

What if I move the charge so that it is not at the centre but at half the radius. Is the charge distribution on sphere affected? If yes then how can we calculate the field at the same old point for the new arrangement?

If we apply superposition principle it is still easy to calculate field due to sphere alone and then for the charge alone but will adding them give actual result? Because the charge distribution is affected by the displaced charge particle.